# Why does Mavis have wings in her hair?

Tags: fairy-tail

She looks cute and all, but why does she have wings sprouting from her roots. Are they supposed to help her with something?

[image: mavis]

Comment: isn't it just her character design? To make the character unique to each other, mangaka tend to add some adornments to the charater so we can recognize them easily

Comment: But she also seems able to move them at will sometimes (ex. episode 157) which would indicate its a body part, so who knows. I honestly came here wondering why she seems able to move her hair and wings at will....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have to vote for the hair accessory theory.  And, we know from the *Fairy Tail Zero* arc that she always wanted to meet a fairy. So, fairy wing headband, with the headband part hidden in the hair? For most of the *Fairy Tail Zero* arc, she is shown with her hair wings. But in episode 97, shortly after learning magic, she re-introduces herself as "Black Magic Mavis" .

[image: Black Magic Mavis]

After casting "Law" in episode 98 and 99, she is unconscious and in bed with her tattered clothes having been changed and no hair adornments.

[image: Unconscious Mavis]

After she regains consciousness, I don't believe we ever see her again without her hair wings as far as I can recall except in some flashbacks to her youth in the last episode of the *Fairy Tail Zero* arc, episode 100.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is an additional accessory which is worn by her not for any explicit purpose. Perhaps to resemble an angel or fairy.

Here are some pictures of Mavis Vermillion young without the wings

[image: Mavis Vermillion young]

[image: Mavis Vermillion]

Answer (score 0):

I think her wings are simply something to make her unique, but perhaps they will later be revealed by the artist, creator, etc. ***Mavis is very unique but she still has a plain character. If you think about it she probably could be confused with an regular character. ***Most characters have something about them: Natsu has his scarf, Lucy has her keys and devil tail whip, Grey has his stripping problem. It is probably just one of these qualities each character has.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is not an accessory because in one of the scenes Mavis Vermilion is in, her ears move up and down due to her reaction to a sour food which means they are real. Also she keeps them on even in the water which would get them soaked if just a prop. Even though when Mavis is in the hospital they are gone, it is because as I said they move so they went back into her hair. Still don't believe me? Well when she was a kid she had two cow licks right where her ears would be in the future version of herself. During that time they were still developing. And some other times her ears are down is because she wants them to. And they never fell off when she fell at the grand magic games. So that proves that she has wings for ears. And here is proof:

[image: Bathing]

[image: Sour food]

Comment: Hi. Can you add sources (anime episodes, manga chapters, etc.) to support your claims? Sources are required and highly encouraged on this site, and your claim that she has wings for ears and that they move back into her hair and forth doesn't convince me. It was never shown in the manga that these are like that, so further evidences are needed.

Comment: Also, if the events you are citing are an anime-only thing, then this makes your argument harder to prove. Try to find supporting information that coincides with both the anime and the manga.

Comment: watch fairy tail OVA episode 1 and you will see that her ear moves

Comment: That one instance alone, however, does not prove that her ears can move. As I mentioned, try to find sources that can coincide in both manga and anime which explains that her ears can move. The OVA you mentioned seems to include events that are anime-only. Unless they are stated as canon and that there is official information supporting your claim, it cannot be true.